# Django DRF display field's verbose_name in error message

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When model field validation fail, I would like DRF to return the field verbose_name in the error message.

example :

models.py :

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    myfield = model.CharField(max_length=20,\
                              verbose_name="This is the field",\
                              default="blabla")
```

serialiers.py :

```
class MyClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = ('myfield',)
```

If, POSTED data for this field is more than 20 characters, response payload is:

```
{"myfield":["the error message..........."]}
```

To make a friendlier message for the users (... and easily manage the errors :-) ) , I'd like to use the model field's verbose_name, so the response payload would be :

```
{"This is the field":["the error message..........."]}
```

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is an easy way of doing this. The easiest way would be overriding `errors` property of serializer and changing error keys with verbose name.

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ...
        fields = ('field1', ...)

    @property
    def errors(self):
        # get errors
        errors = super().errors
        verbose_errors = {}

        # fields = { field.name: field.verbose_name } for each field in model
        fields = {field.name: field.verbose_name for field in
                   self.Meta.model._meta.get_fields() if hasattr(field, 'verbose_name')}

        # iterate over errors and replace error key with verbose name if exists
        for field_name, error in errors.items():
            if field_name in fields:
                verbose_errors[str(fields[field_name])] = error
            else:
                verbose_errors[field_name] = error
        return verbose_errors
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally, as I use Vue.js on the frontend, I choose to use [Vee Validate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/). This way, POSTED data is validated on the backend AND the browser. As invalid data isn't posted, this is even lighter for the backend API.

Comment: Interested, and pleased !, to see this is still working with Django 4.2.